# Sound and Images

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio

When I click on image 1 (001.png) I want audio 1 (001.mp3) to play, and the same for image 2/ audio 2and so on. However how do I make it that if image 1 is clicked the audio will still play if Image 2 is clicked. I just want the user to simply click and image and the audio will play, then click another images and different audio will play still while the first audio is playing, however right now I just have that whatever images is clicked on first only will play.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- <audio src="${ ../_assets/images/001.mp3 }" id="audio"></audio>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle b-play" id="play" onclick="play()"></i> -->


<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <script src="scripts.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Draft</title>


    <style>
    .wrapper {
      width:1000px;
       margin-right:auto;
       margin-left:auto;

    }


    body  {
       background-image: url("../_assets/videos/giphy.gif");
        background-color: #cccccc;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
    }


    img {
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
     border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}


img: visted {
      opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">


<!-- <img src="../_assets/images/001.png" height="20%" width="20%"> -->
</div>




    </div>


    <body>

    <script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                      }

 function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio2");
       audio.play();
                 }




   </script>
<div class="purple">
<img src="../_assets/images/001.png"  height="20%" width="20%"  value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src=" ../_assets/images/001.mp3"   > </audio>

<br>
</div> 

<div class="purple">

<img src="../_assets/images/002.png"  height="20%" width="20%"  value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"> 
<audio id="audio2" src=" ../_assets/images/002.mp3" > </audio>


 </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: right now you are just overwriting the play() function

Answer (score 1):

Change your function:play() as follow:

```
<script>
function play(element){
   var audio = element.nextElementSibling;
   audio.play();
}
</script>
```

then, you need to pass the element of DOM.

```
<img src="../_assets/images/002.png"  height="20%" width="20%"  value="PLAY"  onclick="play(this)">
<audio id="audio2" src=" ../_assets/images/002.mp3" > </audio>
```

Because of using nextElementSibling property, the audio tag must be the next tag of img.